Why did I get a USA visa B1/B2 only valid 2 years?
I am a software engineer legally working in France for almost six years. My wife and I applied for a B2 visa to visit my family in the USA, and we received a visa that is only valid for two years. From what I have read online, the validity period for this type of visa is typically 10 years.
Is there a specific reason why the consulate issued us only a two-year visa instead of a 10-year one?
For reference, my passport expires in December 2026. Could this be the reason for receiving a two-year visa instead of a 10-year one?

It may have something to do with your citizenship

What is the nationality of you and your wife?  Because it sounds like you are not French citizens.

Also a B1/B2 visa may be granted up to 10 years.  That doesn't mean it will.  Finally, do you have any extensive travel history to other countries?

Checking the reciprocity information for your country may provide the answer. Travel with a valid visa in an expired passport plus your new passport is allowed so it seems unlikely the 2 year validity is connected to your passport expiry date. When does your French residence permit expire?

Thank you @Traveller, you answered my question finally when I check your link, I can clearly see that my country can have only 24 months not 120 month.

You can post your comment as an answer, I will accept it
